# Посмотрите правильность решения пожалуйста

Tags: pascal

Дано действительное число х. Обчислить у.

> y= sin(x^2-4)+2/cos3x;

Моё решение

```
var 
x, y:real; 
begin 
writeln('Vvedit x'); 
readln(x); 
begin 
y:= sin(sqr(x)-4) + 2/ cos(3*x);
end; 
writeln('y=', y:8:4); 
readln 
end.
```

После [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757972/178988) @Qwertiy обновил так:

```
var 
x, y:real; 
begin 
writeln('Vvedit x'); 
readln(x); 
y:= (sin(sqr(x)-4) + 2) / cos(3*x);
writeln('y=', y:8:4); 
readln 
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, выбирайте для Ваших вопросов заголовки, которые хоть как-то связаны с содержанием.

Comment: @Igor например к этому примеру какой бы вы поставили бы заголовок?

Comment: Формула с тригонометрическими функциями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уверен, что на косинус надо делить двойку, а не всю сумму? Если сумму, то поставь скобки. Вложенные `begin` и `end` лишние. В остальном выглядит нормально.

Обращаю внимание, что `readln` хочет прочитать перевод строки, что может быть важно в случае чтения из файла.

https://ideone.com/C1fNu0 - здесь input заканчивается переводом строки и всё хорошо:

```
1
```

https://ideone.com/gw7XgP - здесь перевода строки нет

```
1
```

и программа тоже работает, но записывает в `stderr` предупреждение

> ./prog: attempt to read past end of Input (error #454 at 402b9e)

Если нужно, чтобы работало без этого сообщенния с случае отсутствия перевода строки, надо заменить `readln` на `read`, как сделано здесь: https://ideone.com/SbWbGn.

Comment: Ага кажется я понял, можешь посмотреть правильно ли я сделал (я внёс правку в код)

Comment: 1. Да. 2. Теперь он формуле не соответствует, потому то в ней ты написал делениетолько двойки. 3. Нехорошо менять вопрос, когда есть ответы.

Comment: сори не знал этого(

Comment: https://ideone.com/C1fNu0 - обрати внимание, что в случае чтения из файла там обязательно нужен завершающий перевод строки.

Comment: в смысле(завершающий перевод строки)? Я просто немного в этом не шарю)

Comment: @BraFik, дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо друг, я просто пытаюсь понять как всё работает, то и парюсь и доспрашиваю.